How to select color of surface when cut an orange?
I want to draw suface when cut an orange. I don't know make a color suface  of orange.

I tried
CSGRegion["Intersection", {Cuboid[{-3, -3, -3}, {2, 3, 4}], 
  Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3]}]



Don't have time for the skin right now:
slice = ImageCrop@Import["https://i.sstatic.net/eAd929dv.jpg"];
ifn = Interpolation[{{{0}, 1, 0}, {{Pi/2}, 1.01, 0}, {{2 Pi/3}, 0.96, 
     0}, {{Pi}, 1, 0}, {{3 Pi/2 + 0.1}, 0.98, 0}, {{2 Pi}, 1, 0}}];
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 1}
  , {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}
  , PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, MaxRecursion -> 2
  , PlotStyle -> Texture[slice], 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}
  , TextureCoordinateFunction -> (ifn[
        2 Pi #5] ({#1, 1382/1394 #2} - 1/2) + 1/2 &), 
  TextureCoordinateScaling -> True
  , Mesh -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 1 - Sqrt[1 - r^2]}
  , {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}
  , PlotPoints -> {100, 60}, MaxRecursion -> 2
  , PlotStyle -> First@DominantColors[slice],
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, Mesh -> None],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
 ]



Looks tasty. Yum

For version 14.1
CSGRegion["Intersection", {Style[Cuboid[{-3, -3, -3}, {2, 3, 4}], 
   Orange], Style[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Yellow]}]



It' s of course the art of painting. Needs many subtleties
SphericalCap[r_, h_, opt__] := 
  SphericalPlot3D[r, 
   {\[Theta], ArcCos[h/r], \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, opt]

hm := SphericalCap[1, 0, PlotStyle -> Specularity[50], 
       Lighting -> 
     {DirectionalLight[RGBColor[1, .3, .1], {{-5, -5, -4}, {-5, 5, 0}}], 
       SpotLight[RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], {0, 0, 5} , 70 Degree]} , 
       Mesh -> None];

 Slice[r_ , h_, opt__] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[ {s r[\[Phi]] Cos[\[Phi]], s r[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Phi]],  h},
   {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s, 0, 1}, opt]

  sl:= Slice[(0.95 -  Sin[8 #1]/12 &), 0, 
   Lighting -> DirectionalLight[RGBColor[1, .7, .1], 
                     {{-5, 5, 4}, {-5, 5, 0}}] , 
   Mesh -> {Table[k Degree, {k, 0.0, 360., 25.0}], 
            {0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.4], Green, Thickness[0.01]], Blue}]

    Show[ {hm , sl}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]


